# Why are solutions to the negative pell equation related to the period of the continued fraction expansion?

Tags: number-theory

I am aware that it is known that if the CF expansion of $\sqrt{N}$ is odd, then there exists a solution to the negative pell's equation: $x^2 - Ny^2 = -1$.

However, I am unsure of why exactly these two things are related. What is it about this odd period that ensures that there exists a solution for such an $N$?

Comment: You should check out a book called "Quadratics", by Richard Mollin. It goes into a lot of detail about this. When you look at the continued fraction of $\sqrt(n)$, you're looking at, among other things, powers of the fundamental unit of the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{n})$, the norm of which may be $1$ or $-1$. One way to begin seeing into this theory is to look at the CF convergents that come at the end of each period - the numerator and denominator there are precisely the solutions of the negative Pell's equation.